# Weak solution of a SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, sde

$\text { Consider the } \operatorname{SDE} d X_{t}=\operatorname{sign}\left(X_{t}\right) d t+d B_{t} \text { on } 0 \leq t \leq T, \text { where } \operatorname{sign}(x)=1\\
\text { for } x>0 \text { and } \operatorname{sign}(x)=-1 \text { for } x \leq 0 \text { . Show that it has a weak solution. }$

**I am not sure if this is the way I am suppose to answer the question but this is how I did it:**

$d x_{t}-\operatorname{sign}\left(x_{t}\right) d t=d B_{t}$

$\text { let } Y_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}-\operatorname{sign}\left(X_{s}\right) d s+\int_{0}^{t} d X_{s}$

We can see here that $\int_{0}^{t}\left|\operatorname{sign}\left(x_{s}\right)\right| d s<\infty$ as sign$(X_s)$ is bounded between -1 and 1.

We can also see that $\int_{0}^{t}\left(d x_{s}\right)^{2}=T<\infty$

Hence $Y_t$ is well defined and is a martingale as $[y, y]_{t}=\int_{0}^{t} \operatorname{sign}^{2}\left(X_{s}\right) d s=T \text { and }$ $\int_{0}^{t} d X_{S}=\int_{0}^{t} d t=T$

Therefore $[Y, Y]_{t}$ is a constant value which is a martingale. And $Y_t$ is Brownian Motion that satisfies the SDE $dX_t$

Answer (score 1):

Based on Karatzas and Shreve's [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387976556), section 5.3.B, Weak Solutions By Means of Girsanov, Proposition 3.6., "the principal method for creating *weak solutions* is the transformation of drift via the Girsanov theorem". Their *proof of the proposition* illustrates the approach.

The only condition that needs to be met is for the drift to have *bounded growth*: if

$$ |b(t,x)| \leq K(1+|x|) $$

for all $t$ and $x$, for some positive constant $K$, then SDE

$$  dX_t = b(t,X_t) dt + dB_t $$

has a weak solution.

Function $\operatorname{sign}$ does meet the condition:

$$ |\operatorname{sign}(x)| < 1 + |x| $$

for all $x$.

*Notes:*

1. Contrast with the *'usual'* conditions for *strong solutions*: both drift and diffusion coefficients are to satisfy global linear growth and Lipschitz conditions. Note that $\operatorname{sign}$ fails Lipschitz badly.
2. The other thing worth mentioning is that, for practical investigations, one can approximate $\operatorname{sign}$ by a sequence of *smooth* functions that converges pointwise to it (see [this article](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387976556) for such research):

$$ f_n(x) = -1_{x<-1/n} + (-n^3x^3/2 + 3nx/2)1_{-1/n\leq x \leq 1/n} + 1_{x>1/n}  $$
and study SDE
$$ dX_t = f_n(X_t) dt + dB_t. $$